# springboot exception-conversion-word default value adds next log to exception log in the same line

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I am using springboot 2.6.5 and using the `logging.level.exception-conversion-word` property in `application.properties` and the `logback.xml` but when ever an exception occurs, the next log line is getting merged to the exception line

`logback.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

`application.properties`

```
logging.level.exception-conversion-word: "%replace(%wEx){'\n','\u2028'}%nopex"
```

However, when ever an exception occurs, the new lines in the exception are replaced and all the entire exception is converted into a single line as expected. But along with it, the next log message what ever it may be, is also getting appended to the exception line which is wired.

```
2023-08-15 14:09:12.337  INFO 31216 --- [azure.com:10255] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb-abcde-westus.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb-abcde-westus.mongo.cosmos.azure.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known     at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211)     at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.openAsync(NettyStream.java:163)     at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.open(NettyStream.java:154)  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180)     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188)    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb-abcde-westus.mongo.cosmos.azure.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)   at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:867)   at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)  at java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:815)  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1291)    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1144)     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1065)     at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203)     ... 6 common frames omitted  2023-08-15 14:11:14.067  INFO 31216 --- [azure.com:10255] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:139, serverValue:416056366}] to mongodb-abcde-westus.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255
```

If noticed, the exception is broken into 2 lines and the 2nd line also contains `"INFO"` log which should be logged in next line

Comment: I think it's because you're replacing the `\n` with `\u2028`. Why is this necessary?

Comment: No @AbhijitSarkar its not because of that. That is just a unicode for new line. it can be either kept as empty like "" or '', but preferred to add so that one can copy paste the logs to a text editor, then easily find and replace with that character to see the exception stack trace in multi line